# Can i upload a video to youtube using curl command in google colab?

Tags: curl, upload, command, google-colaboratory, youtube-data-api

I am not a programmer and just a newbie youtuber. I want to upload my video to Google Drive first, then mount my Google Drive to Google colab and transfer uploaded video from Google Drive to YouTube using the curl command.
I found this curl command by search in google:

```
curl -X POST -i "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ### Your access token ###" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -d "{\"snippet\":{\"categoryId\":\"22\",\"description\":\"Description of uploaded video.\",\"title\":\"Test video upload.\"},\"status\":{\"privacyStatus\":\"private\"}}"
```

Now i have some problems with this:
Can Google Colab execute commands like this curl?
How can i get `### Your access token ###` for execute this command? (please note that i'm not a programmer. I can only create a project in google console and enable youtube and google drive api and get json info file of oAuth but i don't know how to use it to create `### Your access token ###`)
**If someone wants to guide, please guide completely because there may be many YouTubers like me who don't know how to program, but they need this method.**